# Karate: I would like to use retry more efficiently

Tags: api, karate

Karate: I would like to assert to match parts of response

I am getting the json response and like to make retries more efficient by matching in the whole response rather than one static location like example below

**And header Content-Type = 'application/json'**

**And retry until response[0].dealActivities[4].action == "Checked: Driver’s Licence"**

**When method get**

**Then status 200**

**And json  getResponse = response**

**And assert response[0].dealActivities[4].result == "Validated"**

Please suggest a efficient way of doing it.